# how to spilt array base on speicial size in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

i have payload which type is array. I need to split the payload to multiple small array ,each small array has 2000 lines.
for example , source payload

```
[{"n1":1},{"n2":2}.....{"n10000":10001}]
```

```
var pageSize = round(sizeOf(payload)/2000)
```

i need to split the payload into vars.pageSize array.
the use for each to process.  may i know how to split . thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

oh i got

```
   %dw 2.0 
  import * from dw::core::Arrays
 output application/json
 ----
  payload divideBy 2
```